# Legal status of games with similar titles

Tags: legal, copyright

I've been working on a game for around a year and a half named Planetfall, in which you build a colony on a new planet.

I've bee working on it with that title since before the announcement of Age of Wonders: Planetfall. The games have some overlapping mechanics and aesthetic, but other than that it would be clear that my game is not a clone or a rip-off.

I know that I probably should change the name anyway (so there's no confusion between the titles) but I was wondering what the legal status is of a title that was in development since before the announcement of another similar title. If I decided to go ahead and not change the name, what could happen?

Comment: Have you published any of your work while the game has been in development before Age of Wonders did?

Comment: I wouldn't play around with this. Get a proper lawyer and ask the question.

Comment: @TomTsagk Literally none of it was published

Comment: @Engineer Oh, I don't plan on playing around with this. I plan to change the name. But I'm still curious as to what *could* happen.

Comment: If you're asking _here_, you're playing around with it instead of getting formal legal advice.

Comment: Remember: not every question that involves a game is a question for which game developers have the best answers. This question involves a game, but it's really a question about law. So a lawyer will be able to give you a better answer than we can. What we're able to help you with are the *game* parts of your game business — designing and implementing mechanics, stuff like that.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [it is asking for legal advice](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2624/how-should-we-handle-questions-asking-for-specific-legal-advice) and is a [hypothetical question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).